# Java Random Numbers In An Array

Tags: java

So i am kinda new to java and i need help with a problem.
***I have this code:***

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Board
{
    private int NumberOfCards;
    private int NumberOfPairs;
    private int[] DeckOfCards;
    private int CardsRemaining;
    
    public Board(int NumberOfPairs){
        this.NumberOfCards = NumberOfCards;
        this.NumberOfPairs = NumberOfPairs;
        this.CardsRemaining = CardsRemaining;
        DeckOfCards = new int [2*NumberOfPairs];
        Random numbers = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPairs; i++) {
            DeckOfCards[i] = numbers.nextInt();
        }
```

The code above is not completed and there are many classes left to be completed but the 
problem is that:

Lets say that `NumberOfPairs` = 3
This will mean that inside the array we will have the numbers 0,1,2 with random positions and this will also mean that we will have 3 positions of the array "empty" (because the size is 2*`NumberOfPairs`)

**What i am trying to do is for example this:**

Inside the array will still be the numbers 0,1,2 but twice and with random order such as:

1,0,2,2,1,0

Does anyone have any ideas ? Thank you in advance!

Oh yes i forgot to mention that the NumberOfPairs is not certain and will be given by the user via input

Comment: Put the numbers into the array, either `0 0 1 1 2 2` or `0 1 2 0 1 2`, then shuffle it.

Comment: Oh yes i forgot to mention that the NumberOfPairs is not certain and will be given by the user via input

Comment: Then do the same thing, for the input number of pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thought of what you want to do is to get all the numbers inside an array and then suffle them.

---

Firstly, you must create an array with all the numbers that you want. In your case the numbers that you want are from 0 to NumberOfPairs two times. For example if the NumberOfPairs = 3, then the numbers that you have are (0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2). Therefore, you got this code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Board {
    private int NumberOfCards;
    private int NumberOfPairs;
    private int[] DeckOfCards;
    private int CardsRemaining;
    
    public Board(int NumberOfPairs){
        this.NumberOfPairs = NumberOfPairs;
        this.NumberOfCards = NumberOfCards*2;
        this.CardsRemaining = CardsRemaining;
        DeckOfCards = new int [2*NumberOfPairs];
        Random numbers = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCards; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                DeckOfCards[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, you must suffle the numbers. To suffle the numbers, you have to
switch every current position of the array with a random one. So, for this step your code is something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Board {
    private int NumberOfCards;
    private int NumberOfPairs;
    private int[] DeckOfCards;
    private int CardsRemaining;
    
    public Board(int NumberOfPairs){
        this.NumberOfPairs = NumberOfPairs;
        this.NumberOfCards = NumberOfPairs*2;
        this.CardsRemaining = CardsRemaining;
        DeckOfCards = new int [2*NumberOfPairs];
        private int temp;
        private int randomPos;

        Random numbers = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCards; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                DeckOfCards[i] = i;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCards; i++) {
            randomPos = random.nextInt(NumberOfCards);
            temp = DeckOfCards[i];
            DeckOfCards[i] = DeckOfCards[randomPos];
            DeckOfCards[randomPos] = DeckOfCards[temp];                
        }
    }
}
```

And you are done. I hope that I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Random` is *random*, it won't generate sequences like that.  You have to actually make a sequence if that's what you want.

There's a bit of tricky math in the indexes, you should write these out by hand to see how it works.

```
    Integer deck = new Integer[2*NumberOfPairs];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPairs; i++) {
        deck[i*2] = i;
        deck[i*2+1] = i;
    }
```

Now you have a list of values that aren't random but exactly the sequence you want.  Now if you want them to be in a random order you need to `shuffle` them, like a deck of cards.

```
List<Integer> deckList = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( deck) );
Collections.shuffle( deckList );
int i = 0;
DeckOfCards = new int[2*NumberOfPairs];
for( Integer x : deckList )
   DeckOfCards[i++] = x;
```

Now you have some preset values in a random order.  This would be a bit less complicated if you used an `ArrayList` for `DeckOfCards` instead of an plain int array.  (Code is untested.)

(For comparison, I'll write the same code with `DeckOfCards` as an `ArrayList<Integer>`.)

```
DeckOfCards = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPairs; i++) {
   DeckOfCards.add( i );
   DeckOfCards.add( i );
}
Collections.shuffle( DeckOfCards );
```

(One more edit:  if you are actually building a deck of cards, the usual way to do it is just to assign a `List` the numbers 0 through 51 (52 values for each card).  Then a suit is numbers 0 through 3 (space, heart, diamond, club) like this `card / 13` -- that's `card divided by 13` and the face of each card is `card % 13` where the face value of 10 or less are their own number+1, an ace is 0, and the values of jack, queen and king are 10, 11, and 12.)

Comment: Because it is an assigment we have to do it with an array.Thank you for your time though

Comment: Be careful of using `Collections.shuffle()` then.  Your instructor may want you to implement a method like that yourself.